# Strange errors with Visual C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++

Alright, this is my code so far

```
int main()
{
    char buffer[10];
    int arraySize = -1;
    FILE *fp;
    int i;  
    char filename[10];
    int userNo = 1;
    char stockArray[18][15];
    sprintf(filename, "file%d", userNo);
    fp = fopen(filename, "r");
    while(fgets(buffer, 30, fp) != NULL)
    { 
        if(buffer[0] == '<' && buffer[1] == 's')
        {
            arraySize++;
        }
        else if(buffer[0] == '<' && buffer[1] == '/'){printf("< char\n");}
        else
        {
            int t = 0;
            int r = 0;
            while(buffer[t] != '>')
            {
                t++;
            }
            t++;
            char holder[15] = {'\0'};
            while(buffer[t] != '<')
            {
                holder[r] = buffer[t];
                t++;
                r++;
            }
            strncpy(stockArray[arraySize], holder, r);
            printf("%s\n", stockArray[arraySize]);
        }
    }
    fclose(fp);
}
```

I'm running into two strange issues. First, when I do the printf statement, it prints the proper data just fine, then does the following: if the first word is "banana" and the next is "123" it prints "123ana" and then a bunch of weird character that ends with, I kid you not, a smiley face.

Then, after the program is done and finished, I get a "Run-Time Check Failure #2 - Stack around the variable 'filename' was corrupted." error.

I'm using VS2010 and C++, and all my experience thus far has been with GCC and C, where I've never encountered these problems before. Any advice would be appreciated

Comment: You might want to consider actually using C++, instead of writing C code with a C++ compiler. string, vector, fstream, ostringstream etc. make life so much easier.

Comment: @Joe: Sorry, but if he's throwing it at a C++ compiler, it's C++. Just because it's not _canonical_ / modern C++ doesn't change that!

Comment: @tomalak - there's nothing in that code that has anything resembling the C++ language.  This is ultimately a question about the C language and runtime library.

Comment: @Joe: You mean except for the fact that, syntactically, it's 100% valid C++? If he's using Visual C++, _C has nothing to do with it_.

Comment: +1 for "a bunch of weird character that ends with, I kid you not, a smiley face." :)

Answer (score 7):

Your input buffer is 10 chars long

```
char buffer[10];
```

But then you tell fgets to read up to 30 characters into the buffer

```
fgets(buffer, 30, fp)
```

That is likely to have "funny" effects!

Comment: And this problem would have nothing to do with MSVC vs. GCC or C vs. C++.  It's a problem everywhere.

Comment: @Michael: true for most of the issues in this code, if not all of them.

Answer (score 2):

One thing I recognized on visual inspection is that your `holder` is not properly null-terminated. You might add a line

```
holder[r++] = '\0';
```

after your while-loop.

Comment: `holder` is initialized to be zero filled.  However, it's possible that the while loop writes over the last element (or past) it if `buffer` doesn't contain a `'<'` character soon enough.

Answer (score 0):

Its very difficult to point out the problem, without understanding what exactly you're doing, and what the file contains.

But I still suggest one thing and try:

```
strncpy(stockArray[arraySize], holder, r);
stockArray[arraySize][r] = '\0'; //do this before printf!
```

In general, make sure all your c-strings are null-terminated. Or else you will face the usual problem arises due to lack of null character.